# undefined reference to "_stdscr"

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin, ncurses

I am using windows xp + cygwin + gcc and downloaded the [NCurses](http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/ncurses) and unzipped the source and then run the following commands:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

The commands runs without any error or warning and after that created the following file as goodbye.c:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
int main(void){
    initscr();
    addstr("Goodbye, cruel C programming!");
    printf("Goodbye, cruel C programming!");
    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
 }
```

When I run the gcc compiler with following command as:

```
gcc goodbye.c –lncurses –o goodbye
```

then it has shown the following error message:

```
/tmp/ccTCuCdf.o:c.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `_stdscr'
/tmp/ccTCuCdf.o:c.c:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `_stdscr'
/tmp/ccTCuCdf.o:c.c:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `_stdscr'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I can't find the reason for the error and searched the web and thus creating this question

Comment: Is `_stdscr` present in the libraray which you're giving?

Comment: Just compiled the library and your code seems to link fine. Did you run `ldconfig`?

Comment: @NemanjaBoric no what would be proper command to run